# How to set up for selective pushing with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, branching, mercurial, dvcs

I have a situation, when I'm working on a project, but at same time small issues arise which require quick fix. I would like to push just the fixes for these problems to the main repo while keeping the rest locally. Problem is that, as I've already found out, it's not possible to cherry pick changsets when pushing from my repository upwards.

So the question is, how to set up my Hg environment to have such a possibility. I want to preserve all the Hg metadata, so sending patches around is not a option.

BTW, if the whole thing can be managed directly from MercurialEclipse, that would be a big plus.

Comment: This link illustrate on how to manage bug fixing with mercurial. ie: fix a bug in v1.x while working on v2.0 in the same trunk http://hginit.com/05.html

Comment: [check this out](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and do something less complicated for your project

Comment: @ThanosPapathanasiou - I guess, replacing it all with git is not an option too ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D I wasn't suggesting git, just the branching model.

Comment: @ThanosPapathanasiou - ah, OK, looked to me like a contribution to the old "mercurial/git" fight ;) sorry for that!

Comment: @Andreas_D in the mercurial-git fight I take the mercurial side :) It's just that there aren't any mercurial articles that even come close to that one regarding branching models.

Answer (score 3):

I think, we should do it like this:

1. clone the main repository (again)
2. apply your fixes, check in sources locally
3. push the changes back to main
4. delete the clone (we don't need it anymore, so we delete it as soon as possible)
5. synchronize your other repo with main (merge locally)

Comment: cloning from **main** repository takes quite long for me as it's over 100MB in 12000 files to be fetched from remote server.

Comment: You could run a *local main clone* and use it for creating *local project clones* only. Although this requires additional synchronization. But cloning inside a local machine should be quite fast. And pushing/pulling only sends/receives changesets.

Comment: @vartec: Instead of using `hg clone` you can also `rsync` the main repo -- much, *much* faster. The only thing you lose is the `[paths] default = /path/to/main/repo` in the clone's .hgrc file, which you can either edit in yourself, or just specify at push time. If you are *pulling* into the main repo, you'll have to specify the path anyway, so even this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what branches are for -- use them. In this case, I would be developing in my branch while the main line of development was in default. Keep your fixes cleanly in the right branch, merge as necessary. If it is the sort of app where breaking flow and doing a `hg update` hurts, just keep 2 distinct copies locally, pointed at appropriate branches. Working on a hotfix is as expensive as another instance of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If cloning remotely really does take too long, then this (based on [Adreas_D](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87651/how-to-setup-for-selective-pushing-with-mercurial/87653#87653)'s answer) could be much faster:

1. Clone your local repo.
2. Copy the hgrc from your local repo to your local clone (this will make the default path the same for both repos, so push/pull/incoming/outgoing will all point at the server)
3. Update to the tip of your remote repo.
4. Apply the fix and commit.
5. Strip the changesets that you don't want to push (this may require you to enable the mercurial queues extension).
6. Push the changes back up to the remote repo.
7. Delete the clone (or keep it around so that you can do this type of fix more quickly in the future).
8. Pull changes from the remote repo into your normal local repo and merge.

Alternatively, consider a workflow using named branches. That way, you can push your branch changesets up to the server whenever you like, as they won't become part of the `default` branch until they are explicitly merged in.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial Queues is the easiest and fastest way:
1. You have **not** create (and work with) additional (even local) clone
2. You have all non-bugfix changes stored only locally (in your repo)

Another solutions (acceptable) can be
- Named branches (for "work-in-progress");
- [LocalBranch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LocalbranchExtension) extension.

Answer (score 0):

After spotting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293240/tortoisehg-push-branch/3295729#3295729) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3293240/42473) question, it looks like there is another option.

If you do `hg push -r .` then it will push the parent of the current working copy and all of it's ancestors, but nothing else. Using this, you could:

1. Commit or shelve any uncommitted changes.
2. Update to the tip of your remote repo.
3. Apply the fix and commit.
4. Push the just those changes back up to the remote repo.
5. Update back to your local head.
6. Merge in the bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

The quick method would be :
 - to update to the last stable production changeset;

- Make the change, then commit the change;
- Create a version tag;
- Export the patch;
- Update to the working changeset;
- Merge the working changeset with the tag previously create to bring
  back the fix;

For more detail see http://hginit.com/05.html